# polymorphism and interfaces

Tags: polymorphism, overloading

if i have two classes x and y, both extend class w. and x implementing interface z. if i have methods doSomething(w object) and doSomething(x object), what would happen if i call doSomething(x)?

edit:
im implementing this on java, more specifically on android.
im asking this because some classes which implement a specific interface mostly does the same thing when doSomething() is called. but there are special cases which i would like to single out.

Comment: can you be more specific?  Are you refering to the diamond problem or something else?

Comment: this probably depends on the programming language in question, but typically the compiler will choose the method that has the best fitting parameter type, in this case the one taking `x object`.

Comment: Why don't you try? Nothing bad will happen to you. :)

Comment: +1: It's a good question, and I'm tempted to say that it depends on the language. // Given that I don't know which language you are referring to, why don't you try this scenario in your language of choice, and try to invoke methods that are exclusive to w and x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have

```
w object1 = new x();
x object2 = new x();
```

Passing object1 will execute `doSomething(w object)` and passing object2 `doSomething(x object)`.

P.S: Of course depending on the language (talked about C#)

P.P.S: Added parameter names to make it clearer

Comment: -1: This answer assumes that doSomething(w) and doSomething(x) aren't *both* implemented on x.

Comment: w and x are the types, not the variables. Now it should be clear. :)

Comment: @jim G: what happens if they're both implemented on x?

Comment: @mixm: sorry, i was wrong. Of course it works (on C#), too! I would suggest you google "polymorphimsm", "overrding methods", "virtual methods", "overloading methods", "hiding methods". You should be an expert on the topic, after that ;)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the language that you're using.

For instance, in C# it would use doSomething(x object) not doSomething(w object).

However, if you casted it to w then it would use doSomething(w object) like this:

```
doSomething((w) someObjectOfX);
```

or

```
doSomething(someObjectOfX as w);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the compiler will pick the right method depending on the declared type of the variable, not on the actual type stored in it.

Note, the code below declares `W` to be a class, and constructs an instance of it. If you make `W` an interface, and remove its declaration and construction, you'll get the same behavior for `x` and `y` as the program below, interface or class for `W` in this case does not matter.

Let me show you the difference:

```
using System;

namespace SO2851194
{
    class W { }
    class X : W { }
    class Y : W { }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            W w = new W();
            X x = new X();
            Y y = new Y();

            doSomething(w);
            doSomething(x);
            doSomething(y);
        }

        static void doSomething(W w)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("w");
        }

        static void doSomething(X x)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("x");
        }
    }
}
```

Here I declare three variables, of type `W`, `X`, and `Y`, and call `doSomething` passing the three variables, one by one. The output of this program is:

```
w
x
w
```

As expected, the compiler will pick the method that has the best fitting parameter type, and in the case of the `x` variable, it has a method that can take an object of type `X`.

However, due to class inheritance, we can change the declaration of the variables, but keep the object types constructed, so changing the code like this:

```
W w = new W();
W x = new X();   // Notice, changed variable type to W
W y = new Y();   // but keep constructing X and Y
```

This now outputs:

```
w
w
w
```

So the fact that the `x` variable contained an object of type `X` didn't factor into it, the compiler picked the method from the variable type, not its contents.

In C# 4.0, you now have the `dynamic` type, so again changing the code to:

```
dynamic w = new W();
dynamic x = new X();
dynamic y = new Y();
```

again outputs:

```
w
x
w
```

as now the compiler defers picking any method at all until runtime, and at runtime, it sees that the variable named `x` actually contains an object of type `X` and then picks the method with the best fitting parameter type.

Answer (score -2):

you cant have two different methods with the same signatures. Its ambiguous code, compilers wont compile and interpreters will throw an error.

Comment: The signatures are different. The first is class x and the second is class y.  It's a completely legitimate question.